# Should I load all AJAX calls through an API subdomain?

Tags: ajax, api, .htaccess

Normally visiting my website will trip this htaccess rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php$1 [L]
```

So http://example.com/test/1, becomes http://example.com/index.php/test/1

For AJAX calls I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.net
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /api.php$1 [L]
```

So along with a virtual hsot pointing to the same directory as the domain, http://api.example.com/test/1, becomes http://example.com/api.php/test/1

The difference between the two is that index.php will return along with JSON, the base html framework for the initial page load. While the api will just return JSON

I also have REAL API calls that other servers can make that are not used on the website via http://api.example.com.

Does anyone see a problem with this? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with plain JSON is that you cannot do cross domain AJAX requests, that includes subdomains. But for every problem is a solution. There is a technique called [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), that means that you just need to add a special header to allow that cross domain calls.

So if you just want to allow the domain example.com the header should look like this:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com
```

If you want to allow access from all domains use the asterisk instead:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

And finally the php code, you must put this line php before any other output else you will get a warning and the ajax call will fail:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com");
```